# Lie algebra definition problem.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The question is: How do we define the Lie algebra generated by a set of vector fields?

I'm reading Kobayashi's book Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry and in the proof of the next theorem he uses that on the first line of the proof.
[image]

So my question is how do we define $g^*$? My first guess is that is the vector subspace spaned by $S$ together with the Lie bracket, but down the proof he proves that $S$ actually spans $g^*$ as vector spaces.

Comment: You take all the linear combinations in $S$ and then all the possible Lie brackets (there is a well defined Lie bracket of vector fields). It is not a priori that $S$ generates $\mathfrak g^*$ as vector space. For example, $\mathbb C[x]$ is generated by $\{x\}$ as algebra, but $\{x\}$ doesn't generate $\mathbb C[x]$ as vector space.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks!

Comment: For another point of view, first you take the Lie algebra of all vector fields on $M$, then take the intersection of all Lie subalgebras which are a superset of $S$, and show this intersection again forms a Lie subalgebra.